# Protobuf : Problems connecting C# and java sides

Tags: c#, java, protocol-buffers

I'm writing C# protobuf client which is expected to connect to Java-written server side, but I ran into some issues. I'm using protobuf-csharp-port. I must initialize an `IRpcDispatch`instance like this:

```
var rpcClient = RpcClient.ConnectRpc(Iid, Protocol, Server, Endpoint);
```

So I have to specify 4 parameters.
But on java side everytthing is much more straightforward:

```
ServerRpcConnectionFactory rpcConnectionFactory = SocketRpcConnectionFactories
.createServerRpcConnectionFactory(host, port);
```

So here we have only host & port.

My question is - what are IID, protocol & endpoint, which I must specify on C# side? Which values should I supply?
I didn't have to specify them on java when writing the server...

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've removed the `protobuf-net` tag, as protobuf-csharp-port is unrelated; I've also forwarded this to Jon ;p

Comment: It looks like you're using protobuf-csharp-rpc and protobuf-socket-rpc - I don't know whether these actually use the same protocols...

Comment: Thanks guys. I'd apreciate if you could point me to some C# examples which are the closest to Java implementation

Comment: @DmitryVyakhirev - did you manage to solve the problem? Have any ideas to share?

Comment: @Elist - no, I didn't find a solution that makes sense to go for. I re-implemented my components using Apache Thrift. I liked it much better. It supports many programming languages and has a number of other cool features.

Comment: Thanks, I look into Thrift.